# Android MYSQL data insert

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a booking application. So I have a table called description where a company can add their informations. Second table is called booking, and in this table, people can make a booking to one of the company informations.

Table description:

1. company_id Auto-Increment
2. companytitle Text
3. jobtitle Text
4. description Text
5. startDate Text
6. endDate text

Table bookings:

1. id Auto-Increment
2. companytitle Text In this field, when you make a booking, it will display the company name of the company
3. name Text
4. surname Text - Your surname
5. date Text - the date when you can make a booking
6. company_booking_id - Here, when you make a booking you have an ID,
   that will be the FK of the companyid that is in the first table.

Php script:

```
"insert into bookings (companytitle, name, surname, date, company_booking_id) values ('$companytitle','$name', '$surname', '$date','$company_booking_id' )";
```

Now, lets say you are logging in as a User, you have a customLayout with the informations that every company has put, you choose one company, how can you make a booking to that specific company ? How the app will know for which company you made a booking ?

Exemple:
First company

- Company Title - X
- Company Description - Selling carrots
- Start Date - 20 july 9:00 PM
- End Date - 21 july 9:00 pm

Second company:

- Company Title - Y
- Company Description - Selling potatoes
- Start Date - 20 july 9:00 PM
- End Date - 21 july 9:00 pm

These are 2 different companies, I'm logging in as a user and I want to make a booking to one of these, how the app will know for which company I made the booking ? :D

BookingAddClass:

```
> public class BookingAdd {
>     String companytitle;
>     String name;
>     String surname;
>     String data;
> 
>     public BookingAdd(){}
> 
>     public BookingAdd(String companytitle, String name, String surname, String date) {
>         this.companytitle = companytitle;
>         this.nume = nume;
>         this.prenume = prenume;
>         this.data = data;
>     }
> 
>     public String getCompanytitle() {
>         return companytitle;
>     }
> 
>     public void setCompanytitle(String companytitle) {
>         this.companytitle = companytitle;
>     }
> 
>     public String getNume() {
>         return nume;
>     }
> 
>     public void setNume(String nume) {
>         this.nume = nume;
>     }
> 
>     public String getName() {
>         return name;
>     }
> 
>     public void setSurname(String surname) {
>         this.surname = surname;
>     }
> 
>     public String getData() {
>         return data;
>     }
> 
>     public void setData(String data) {
>         this.data = data;
>     } }
```

Every user when is making an account has to complete their personal info.

```
> public class BookingsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
>     Context c;
>     ArrayList<CompanyData> informations = new ArrayList<>();
>     LayoutInflater inflater;
>     Button makeABooking;
> 
>     public Button getMakeABooking() {
>         return makeABooking;
>     }
> 
>     public void setMakeABooking(Button makeABooking) {
>         this.makeABooking = makeABooking;
>     }
> 
>     public BookingsAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<CompanyData> informations) {
>         this.c = c;
>         this.informations = informations;
>         inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>     }
> 
>     public BookingsAdapter() {
>         super();
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public int getCount() {
>         return informations.size();
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public Object getItem(int i) {
>         return informations.get(i);
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public long getItemId(int i) {
>         return i;
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
>         CompanyData companyData = informations.get(i);
> 
>         if(view == null) {
>             inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>             view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bookingslayout, null);
>         }
>         // ImageView logo = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.logoImageView);
>         TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.companyTitletextview);
>         TextView description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.companyDescriptiontextview);
>         TextView startDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewstart);
>         TextView endDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textviewend);
> 
>         title.setText(companyData.getTitle());
>         description.setText(companyData.getDescription());
>         startDate.setText(companyData.getStartDate());
>         endDate.setText(companyData.getEndDate());
> 
> 
>         return view;
> 
> 
>     }
> 
>     @Override
>     public CharSequence[] getAutofillOptions() {
>         return new CharSequence[0];

}
```

}

Layout with the listview, I dont have any special info in it at the moment..

```
> public class Bookings extends AppCompatActivity {
>     ListView listView;
>     final static String urlAdress = "http://localhost/bookingslist.php";
> 
>     public void makebookingbutton(View view){
>         BookingAdd addbooking = new BookingAdd();
>         //add the booking
>         Toast.makeText(Bookings.this, "Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
>     }
> 
> 
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.activity_bookings);
>         listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
> 
>         BookingsDownloader downloader = new BookingsDownloader(Bookings.this,urlAdress,listView);
>         downloader.execute();
>     } }
```

Comment: it\s not clear what you mean by "how the app will know" ? you need to post more details on how your app handles the (company selecting) and how booking is made (api call? what parameters are you sending from app to api?) ... you can send `company_booking_id` as one of the parameters to the booking API?!

Comment: Once you are logging in as a user, you are redirected to the bookings list(custom list), in the custom list I have all the services, each service has a button, once you press it data are inserted into the database. This is still not implemented because I dont know how to take the company_booking_id of the company that I selected :(.

Comment: I'm using AsynkTask so it will be something like this, once the button is clicked                     myClass.execute(companytitle.getCompanyTitle(), description.getDescription(), startDate.getstartDate(), enddate.getendDate(), yourDate.getyourDate(),companyBookingId.getCompanyBookingId());

Comment: you need to share code of that list view, if you are using a CustomAdapter, you can use a `Company` object (create one) and use it in the adapter, and use it to get company info and send it's ID among the request, also you  may want to add a field to booking table (user_id) so you can know which user did which booking.

Comment: Ok, I edited the original post, I added the info :D